# Why this C code fails if I quit the first printf?

Tags: c, malloc, sizeof, realloc

If I quit the first printf, about sizeof my struct List, the realloc code quits with this error: free(): double free detected in tcache 2

Why?

What is doing the printf in order this to work?

And if I enter a scanf method in order to get the var frase of the user, then it hangs if the var frase is greater than 5 characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct List {
  char clave;
  int valor;
};  


void add(struct List *myList, char c, int v, int *elementos);
int comprobarCaracter(struct List *myList, char c, int elementos);

int main() {
    
    struct List *myList;
    int elementos = 0;
    
    // this printf
    printf("Sizeof List %i\n", (int) sizeof(struct List));

    myList = (struct List*) malloc(1 * (int) sizeof(struct List));
    
    char frase[100] = "caracola";

    int tam = strlen(frase);
    printf("frase len: %i\n", tam);

    for (int i=0; i < tam; i++) {
        char caracter = frase[i];
        int existe = comprobarCaracter(myList, caracter, elementos);
        if (existe == -1) {
            printf("caracter no existe %c\n", caracter);
            add(myList, caracter, 1, &elementos);
        }
        
    }
   
    free(myList);

    return 0;
}


void add(struct List *myList, char c, int v, int *elementos) {
      int ele = *elementos;
      ele++;
      *elementos = ele;
      printf("elementos: %i\n", *elementos);
      myList = (struct List*) realloc(myList, ele * sizeof(struct List));
      myList[ele-1].clave = c;
      myList[ele-1].valor = v;

}
  
int comprobarCaracter(struct List *myList, char c, int elementos) {
     printf("comprobando caracter %c\n", c);
     
     int existe = -1;      
     for (int i=0; i < elementos; i++) {
        if (myList[i].clave == c) {
            printf("caracter existe %c\n", c);
            existe = i;
            myList[i].valor++;
            break;
        }
     }
     return existe;
     
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Pacosal

Comment: You can try this here: https://onlinegdb.com/m0mmWJhDE

Comment: Function `add()` takes a *copy* of the pointer value passed, and does not modify the original. Since you reallocate the (copy of the) pointer, the original is left dangling. I suggest you change the function type and `return` the new pointer value, which can be assigned to the original by the caller. `myList = add(myList, caracter, 1, &elementos);`

Comment: Another way of Weather Vane solution is to ask for a pointer of pointer of myList:
`void add(List_t **myList, char c, int v, int *elementos);`

Comment: Thanks, I've used the first one and it works perfectly.